# What is the life expectancy of an earthquake safety valve?

Tags: valve, natural-gas, earthquake, gasleak

There are many sites that recommend an earthquake safety valve to be installed on a gas line but they also sell service of installing so seems like they are just selling their service. Considering that there are moving parts in an earthquake valve what is the expected life of an earthquake safety valve and how frequently it should be tested?

Interesting that some services propose charging in the thousands per install but many plumbers will do for around $350 including parts and labor. This article written in 95 indicates they will install for $75 but some charge 200.

https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1992-08-12-vw-5418-story.html

Looks like gas co does not recommend them because not everyone knows how to reset the valve and relight their water heaters so it is a logistical issue when an earthquake hits for the gas company to restore everyone's gas.

Comment: Maybe hit up a couple of manufacturer sites to see what they say. Sure, they've got a vested interest in selling replacements when the old ones "go bad", but, if you're required to have one (or just feel better about it), then sticking with the mfgr instructions seems to be the way to go. BTW - is this for water, gas, something else? It's been a while since I lived in earthquake country and I doubt these were "a thing" when I did...

Comment: The "thousands per install" category need to make sure they have enough cash on hand for when they get sued for a defective install by the $16/hour newbie which they sent out. The "$350" camp assumes you will barely remember their face let alone their name and won't even mention an inspection.

Comment: Little firefighter products indicate a 30 year warranty on amazon.
https://www.amazon.com/Gas-Shutoff-Valve-3-4/product-reviews/B00MY62X62/